# Android Smart Lock setResultCallback is not getting called

Tags: android, google-play-services, credentials, google-smartlockpasswords

I have been following https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials to try to automatically sign in a user if they have saved their credentials to the new Android Smart Lock feature in chrome. I have followed the guide exactly, but my callback that I pass into setResultCallback() is not getting called. Has anyone run into this problem before?

There is no error message or anything, it just doesn't get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that the Google API client is not connected, try calling `connect()` in the `onStart()` method of your activity, or if you are using a recent version of Play Services, we added automatic management of the API client to make this easier, really simplifying things and avoiding common problems.

Just call `enableAutoManage()` when building the `GoogleApiClient`:

```
    // "this" is a reference to your activity
    mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
            .build();
```

Then you can make an API request without having to call `mCredentialsApiClient.onConnect()` at any point, the Google API client's lifecycle will be managed automatically for you. e.g.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    CredentialRequest request = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
            .setSupportsPasswordLogin(true)
            .build();
    Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsApiClient, request).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<CredentialRequestResult>() {
                public void onResult(CredentialRequestResult result) {
                    // result.getStatus(), result.getCredential() ... sign in automatically!
...
```

Check out a full sample app at on Github: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/credentials-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/credentialsbasic/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

I tired the official demo app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials), and it worked.

Basically, the `setResultCallback()` will be get called when `save`, `request` and `delete`

For save:

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mCredentialsApiClient, credential).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "SAVE: OK");
                            showToast("Credential Saved");
                            hideProgress();
                        } else {
                            resolveResult(status, RC_SAVE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

For request:

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsApiClient, request).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<CredentialRequestResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(CredentialRequestResult credentialRequestResult) {
                        if (credentialRequestResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Successfully read the credential without any user interaction, this
                            // means there was only a single credential and the user has auto
                            // sign-in enabled.
                            processRetrievedCredential(credentialRequestResult.getCredential(), false);
                            hideProgress();
                        } else {
                            // Reading the credential requires a resolution, which means the user
                            // may be asked to pick among multiple credentials if they exist.
                            Status status = credentialRequestResult.getStatus();
                            if (status.getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
                                // This is a "hint" credential, which will have an ID but not
                                // a password.  This can be used to populate the username/email
                                // field of a sign-up form or to initialize other services.
                                resolveResult(status, RC_HINT);
                            } else {
                                // This is most likely the case where the user has multiple saved
                                // credentials and needs to pick one
                                resolveResult(status, RC_READ);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

For delete:

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.delete(mCredentialsApiClient, mCurrentCredential).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        hideProgress();
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            // Credential delete succeeded, disable the delete button because we
                            // cannot delete the same credential twice.
                            showToast("Credential Delete Success");
                            findViewById(R.id.button_delete_loaded_credential).setEnabled(false);
                            mCurrentCredential = null;
                        } else {
                            // Credential deletion either failed or was cancelled, this operation
                            // never gives a 'resolution' so we can display the failure message
                            // immediately.
                            Log.e(TAG, "Credential Delete: NOT OK");
                            showToast("Credential Delete Failed");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Also you can clone the project in my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/SmartLock-android), set the `SHA1` in your console [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/get-started#configure_your_console_name_project).

At this point you should be ready to go :)

Comment: Does this helped you? If so, please accept. If not please tell me, thanks

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I am calling Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsApiClient, request).setResultCallback(...) but the callback is never called.

Comment: Have you tried demo app [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/SmartLock-android)? I tried from the official, `setResultCallback(...)` really worked. So can you post you code that I can check and help you?

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing mCredentialsApiClient.connect(); which was mentioned in the sample code but not the development guide. Thanks for your help!